# How to read string format and seperate fields:value in ( C )

Tags: c

i have a string format example :

1)

```
   DATASET:students name:STRING sid:STRING graduated:BOOLEAN year:INTEGER gpa:INTEGER
```

2)

```
 typedef  struct param{
          char *Name;
          char *Value;
          struct param *next;
          }params;
```

we must get from string all fieldname:value and add to linked list or array of struct.

Comment: Seems pretty similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27738177/3933332 don't you think too?

Comment: in c language i need

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking code without any attempt from the OP shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the whole line using `fgets()`
2. Break the line using `strtok()` using space as deleimter and store the respective strings in an array.
3. Then break the contents of an array one by one using `strtok()` using `:` as delimter.
   Please note that `strtok()` will modify your passed string.
4. Now you can copy the data from the the array to your respective structure fields